# Alternative for deferred length character arrays in common blocks? (crashes gfortran)

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran, deferred, array-shape

My goal is to call a C function to allocate Fortran dynamic arrays (which works fine for integer, real, logical already).  But I'm having trouble with the gfortran compiler, character strings and common blocks.  Here's a distillation of my roadblock:

```
      subroutine sub1()
      character(len=:), pointer :: local
      character(len=:), pointer :: comm
      common /commie/ comm
      comm = local
      return
      end
```

For some reason placing such a pointer into a common block confuses gfortran:

```
ghart@el9$ gfortran sub1.f
sub1.f:6:72:
    6 |       comm = local
      |                                                                        
1
internal compiler error: in gfc_conv_variable, at fortran/trans-expr.c:3036
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
ghart@el9$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) **11.3.1** 20220421 (Red Hat 11.3.1-2)
```

for years...

```
ghart@el8$ gfortran sub1.f
sub1.f:6:0:
       comm = local
internal compiler error: in gfc_conv_variable, at fortran/trans-expr.c:2726
....
ghart@el8$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) **8.5.0** 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-10)

ghart@el7$ gfortran sub1.f
sub1.f: In function ?sub1?:
sub1.f:6:0: internal compiler error: in gfc_conv_variable, at fortran/trans-expr.c:1796
       comm = local
 ^
ghart@el7$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) **4.8.5** 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
```

(could be this: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55735)

But my real question: **is there an alternative definition for a dynamically sized character string array** (that I can put in a common block)?  All I need is the declaration, which would allow existing Fortran code that uses something like:

```
  character(kind=ucs4, len=xxx) stringarray1(yyy)
```

to work as is, but is *not* this one:

```
  character(kind=ucs4, len=:) stringarray1(:)
```

To add some more context, here's the working code for integers:

```
        SUBROUTINE shob_arrI(ptr, decl, sz, grp)
          USE ISO_C_BINDING
          integer, pointer :: ptr(:)
          character*(*) decl
          integer*8 sz
          integer, pointer :: grp
        END SUBROUTINE shob_arrI
....
      integer, pointer :: grpX
      integer, pointer :: i1(:)
      common /grpX/ i1

      call shob_arrI(i1, 'integer i1(7)', 0_8, grpX)
```

shob_arrI is a C function which parses the definition ("integer i1(7)"), builds the gfortran GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR structure, and maps the actual array data area to a shared memory file (this is for multi-process access to shared arrays).

So what I'm looking for is the corresponding "integer, pointer :: ptr(:)" declaration for a character string array.

Comment: What a strange mix of features. I am not surprised the compiler writer may not have tested these. But pointers cannot be in a common block. Ever. What you are doing in C with the Fortran descriptors definitely sound suspicious too. You should be using `ISO_Fortran_binding.h`. But really, normally one just allocates the memory in Fortran. This header is used rather exceptionally.

Comment: Note also that `comm` is a scalar and not an array.

Comment: As previously commented, common blocks are almost certainly the wrong way to go about what you are trying to do, as is playing with GCC internals. Help providing a workaround for an ICE may well actually be causing more harm than good. (That said, with only a sketch of the "working" integer code instead of a [mre] it's hard to tell.) Proper dynamic memory management and C interpretation must surely be better. It'll certainly be more portable.

Comment: "... for years"?  So, you've had years to supply a patch?  Open-source software does not write itself.

Comment: @steve, you misunderstand.  I just discovered this two days ago - but I show it is reproducible all the way back to 4.8.5 (circa 2015?)

Comment: @Vladimir, perhaps I wasn't very clear in my description.  The problem occurs with only a single feature applied: the common label.  The rest of my strange mix isn't relevant, I just mentioned them for context.  But you are correct, what I'm doing is exceptional - using shared memory mapped FORTRAN arrays is not something I have found existing examples of.  And I wanted to allow run-time sizing for these, which is where the deferred attribute comes in.

Comment: The fact that it exists that far back means very few people use that programming paradigm.  The best, and sometimes only, way to ensure something is fixed is joining the open-source software effort.  Have you engaged the gfortran developers?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `common` blocks.

```
module str
   character(len=:), pointer :: local
   character(len=:), pointer :: comm
end module str

subroutine sub1()
   use str
   local = 'abc'
   comm => local
   ! comm = local    ! Copy data into anonymous memory
   return
end
```

Edited:  This allows your code to compile.  Have no idea if the result is correct.  Don't care.

```
diff --git a/gcc/fortran/trans-expr.cc b/gcc/fortran/trans-expr.cc
index f052d6b9440..52d55322b04 100644
--- a/gcc/fortran/trans-expr.cc
+++ b/gcc/fortran/trans-expr.cc
@@ -2989,7 +2989,8 @@ gfc_conv_variable (gfc_se * se, gfc_expr * expr)
   sym = expr->symtree->n.sym;
   is_classarray = IS_CLASS_ARRAY (sym);
   ss = se->ss;
-  if (ss != NULL)
+
+  if (ss != NULL && ss->info)
     {
       gfc_ss_info *ss_info = ss->info;
 
@@ -3091,7 +3092,8 @@ gfc_conv_variable (gfc_se * se, gfc_expr * expr)
         se->string_length = sym->ns->proc_name->ts.u.cl->backend_decl;
       else
         se->string_length = sym->ts.u.cl->backend_decl;
-      gcc_assert (se->string_length);
+      if (!sym->ts.deferred)
+        gcc_assert (se->string_length);
     }
 
   gfc_typespec *ts = &sym->ts;
```

Edit**2: While the patch allows the example provided here to compile, a complete program leads to ICEs elsewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm dealing with a very large code base (been in constant development since the 90's, starting with F77).  So I really didn't want to refactor all the 1000's of files to move from common to module - but now you have given me a choice: apply your beautiful patch (THANK YOU!) and start managing my own release of gfortran *or* refactor common to modules and retrain all our FORTRAN developers (a few dozen across Brazil, India, Austria, Germany and the US) to use modules :)

Comment: You don't have to start managing your own release of gfortran.  You (and your international legion of developers) could make an effort  to contribute patches back to GCC to fix gfortran.  Not only would you fix the problem for your project, but you would fix it for everyone.  Bugs are seldomly  spontaneously fixed.

Comment: true, I may have to do that.  I need this for at least gcc 4.8, 8.5, 11.3, immediately, so I was skeptical that the GCC crew at RedHat would be willing to support me.  I never use gfortran myself, except to create the interface definitions to access my C code, so I had no idea if this issue was a problem with my syntax, some idiomatic limitation of FORTRAN, or a known limitation.  Frankly, I was shocked that such a simple concept: deferred length character string pointer in a common block; seems to be a completely unknown idea to FORTRAN developers (no response internally here ;).

Comment: @Geoff Frankly, I am shocked that someone pushes so such a weird mix. Modern deferred-length strings and decades obsolete common blocks. There is a simple reason why the bug may remain open for so long. Very few people use such a combination. Do you really have to share the data through common blocks?

Comment: The name of the language is Fortran.  It hasn't been FORTRAN since 1990.  The bug will never be fixed by the gfortran developers in anything older than 11.3 as older releases are EOL.  If you're simply writing glue code to a C library, you might want to look into modern Fortran ISO C Binding feature.

Comment: @Vladimir - again, you are preaching to the choir.  I led an effort, more than 15 years ago, to stop using Fortran completely - as most of our development moved to C long ago.  And the group leads all thought that was a great idea.  However, if you've ever worked on a large software system, which is sold all over the world, you learn that individual project priorities always take precedence over efforts like this which have only long term benefits.  Today, just my test bed has around 3000 .f's, with at least 1000 common block definitions - so my goal is: minimize impact.

Comment: @Geoff: Among Fortran programmers (such as, people answering stackoverflow questions tagged "fortran") you might find sympathy for modernizing legacy Fortran. Less so for rewriting it in C.